# Prob: SQL Server 2008 R2: Certificates tab not displaying in protocol properties (Server Config->Network Config)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssl, configuration

I'm trying to get SSL encryption enabled (not forced - not all clients require encryption) on my SQL Server 2008 R2 box.

I've created a valid certificate and imported it to the server. From the MMC snap in, I chose to add Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal -> Certificates

So far so good, but then when I opened the SQL Server Configuration Manager, went to SQL Server Network Configuration, chose Protocols for `MSSQLSERVER`, and then chose TPC/IP -> Properties, there was no Certificates tab visible from which I can choose a certificate.

What determines whether or not this tab shows up? I'm sure it's a simple setting somewhere that everyone but me has figured out, but I can't find any documentation, wiki, etc. that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was that I was looking in the wrong place.  I took these steps to resolve my issue:

1. From SQL Server Configuration Manager, I chose Protocols for MSSQLSERVER, then right clicked on that and chose Properties.  From there I found the certificates tab.
2. Choosing the Cert was easy - done.
3. On restarting MSSQL I got an error and it wouldn't start.  Quick Bing and traced it to the fact that the account MSSQL is running on didn't have access to that cert.  I went to the Cert MMC and then from there I chose the cert, right clicked and went to All Tasks->Manage Private Keys.  From there I simply gave access rights to the SQL service account.

Restarted the SQL service and voila!  Problem solved.